# Undesired Togglebutton icon when not using a Theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-togglebutton

I'm having an issue with Togglebuttons when not specifying a theme.

If I use any theme they look fine but if I remove the android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tag from AndroidManifest.xml Togglebuttons add an unwanted icon.

Sample image here:

[image]

I made a sample project with just a togglebutton with following xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                   
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">  

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how it looks.

[image]

[image]

I think I need to define a new theme inheriting from device default theme to override the togglebutton icon but I've had no success so far.